# In Unreal, How do I hide function inputs based on Enum selected?

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint, unreal-development-kit, unreal

I'm created a blueprinteditable function.
First parameter is an Enum.
The rest of the parameters should either be hidden or visible based on the Enum selected.

Like "EditConditionsHide" but for UFunctions.

https://benui.ca/unreal/uproperty-edit-condition-can-edit-change/

For Reference, in Blender Geometry nodes, there are several nodes that alter available inputs based on an enum selection.  Like "Quadrilateral" Node will have "width/height" when "Rectangle" is selected, but will have 4 vectors (Point 1-4) when "Points" is selected.

I'm trying to create new nodes for Unreal's Geometry Scripting that matches the function and layout of nodes in Blender's Geometry Nodes.

I haven't found any information on anything to try.
All the documentation on Ufunctions that I've found doesn't give any option to hide parameters based on enum input.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with vanilla `UFUNCTIONS`. You need to create your own custom K2Nodes. They are not trivial to make. I would suggest to split your function into multiple functions instead.

If you want to go down the route of custom K2Nodes, here is a good starting point for creating your own custom nodes: https://olssondev.github.io/2023-02-13-K2Nodes/

Comment: Thanks.  But unfortunately, they can't be split.  I'm creating one-to-one translations from Blender's Geometry nodes to Unreal's Geometry Scripting.

Comment: In that case, it would be worth learning how to create custom K2Nodes which will allow you to do what you are looking for above and more.